# Wrong values returned by Elasticsearch's script_field for array.values

Tags: arrays, elasticsearch

I've tried to retrieve array values from my data by using `script_fields`, but I received inconsistent results.

My mapping:

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/test/user/_mapping -d '
{
  "user": {
    "properties": {
      "id": {
        "type": "string",
        "index": "not_analyzed"
      },
      "other_ids": {
        "type": "string",
        "index": "not_analyzed"
      }
    }
  }
}
'
```

Some test data:

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/test/user/id1 -d '
{
  "id": "id1",
  "other_ids": [
    "id2",
    "id3"
  ]
}
'

curl -XPUT localhost:9200/test/user/id2 -d '
{
  "id": "id2",
  "other_ids": [
    "id1"
  ]
}
'

curl -XPUT localhost:9200/test/user/id3 -d '
{
  "id": "id3",
  "other_ids": [
    "id1",
    "id2"
  ]
}
'
```

The "simplified" query:

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/test/user/_search?pretty=1'  -d '
{
  "fields": [
    "_source"
  ],
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "script_fields": {
    "other_id_script": {
      "lang": "groovy",
      "script": "doc[\"other_ids\"].values"
    }
  }
}
'
```

The relevant parts from the answer:

```
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 3,
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [ {
      "_source":{"id":"id1","other_ids":["id2","id3"]},
      "fields" : {
        "other_id_script" : [ [ "id1", "id2" ] ]
      }
    }, {
      "_source":{"id":"id2","other_ids":["id1"]},
      "fields" : {
        "other_id_script" : [ [ "id1", "id2" ] ]
      }
    }, {
      "_source":{"id":"id3","other_ids":["id1","id2"]},
      "fields" : {
        "other_id_script" : [ [ "id1", "id2" ] ]
      }
    } ]
  }
```

As we can see the values of `other_id_script` are different from the current doc's `other_ids` values in the first two cases.

Is it an error, or am I missed something?

(The whole script can be found here: https://gist.github.com/baloghz/c27e39ad419a6f4684ab)

Comment: i'm unable to replicate it in elasticsearch version 1.3.0 , java 1.7.0_65

Comment: Thanks for trying! I have elasticsearch version 1.3.0 , java 1.7.0_67-b01.
What kind of settings can cause this kind of strange results (some kind of cache related maybe)?

Comment: I'm noticing the same problem. Were you able to figure out how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this problem was addressed in Elasticsearch [issue #8576](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/8576), was fixed by [commit d22645c](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/commit/d22645cbfc3558e648da7a4dde07ca69a7b7df55), and is live in versions 1.3.6, 1.4.1, and 1.5.0.

The author of the issue also gave a workaround:

```
"script": "doc[\"other_ids\"].values.take(100)"
```